# Using both EL 1.2 and 2.2 syntax (el-api-2.2.) in the same project (to coexist JSP working with 1.2 and JSF working with 2.2)

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, maven, el

I have a special problem with a project that I have, I'm using both the two version of the el-impl jar in a project; I'm using v1.2 to manage my jsp and the 2.2 to manage my JSF files, I want a solution to coexist the two version because I need both my jsp and my jsf files

the problem is, when I add the EL 2.2 relating  `param-context`, jsp doesn't work and I get this exception because jsp files doesn't work with the  2.2 version:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: It appears the JSP version of the container is older than 2.1 and unable to locate the EL RI expression factory, com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.  If not using JSP or the EL RI, make sure the context initialization parameter, com.sun.faces.expressionFactory, is properly set.
```

and when I remove the EL 2.2 relating  `param-context`, I mean this part from the web.xml:

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

If removed, the el-impl2.2 is not supported , so when I access to a JSF file, I get this exception ( because I don't have the 2.2 version supported )

```
    org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 20.
    Was expecting one of:
        "}" ...
        "." ...
        "[" ...
        ">" ...
        "gt" ...
        "<" ...
        "lt" ...
        ">=" ...
        "ge" ...

    ...


Jul 25, 2012 5:39:24 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container
```

can someone help me with a solution to use both the two EL jars into the same project to allow me competing my project with containing JSP and JSF files, by the way I m using Maven , so  here is a part of my dependencies :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency> 

      <dependency>
<groupId>javax.el</groupId>
<artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

a part of my web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        version="2.5">


        <filter>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
                <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
                <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            /WEB-INF

    /applicationContext.xml
                </param-value>
            </context-param>


            <context-param>     
            <param-name>com.sun

.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
    </context-param>

        <!--  to enable Spring MVC we need to add in this web.xml: -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/me/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
            <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
            </listener-class>
          </listener>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>


        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

I'm also using tiles if that will cause any problem please tell me about, and
Thank you for helping me in this

Answer (score 0):

This is in no way possible to do.

You can instead however run them in two separate projects but including the appropriate EL jar in the project directly and removing the servlet container's pre-packaged EL jar from the servlet container lib folder.  This would at least allow the two applications to run on the same web container, server, DNS name and port number.